# angular not updating index after splicing value from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

below is html code,

```
 <button ng-click="Delete(list.Id)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
```

and this is angular code

```
  $http.post('/Companies/Delete', { model: mod })
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result.data == true)
                $scope.CompaniesList.splice(index, 1);
            //$scope.$apply();
            showtoastNotification('Deleted !', 'Company deleted from database', 'info');
            //$scope.cancel();
            //loadCurrentPage();
        }, function () {
            showtoastNotification('Error !', 'Something went wrong please try again later', 'error');
        })
```

when i delete an item from list then after deleting it perfectly deletes previous items but not items from further indexes without refreshing page

Comment: Where is `index` defined for `$scope.CompaniesList.splice(index, 1);`?

Comment: OluwafemiSule issue solved there was issue in index, thanks for pointing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code

```
$scope.CompaniesList.splice(index, 1);
```

will only delete one item at index `index`.

If you want to delete all items after  index `index` then you need to count how many items to delete starting from `index`.

```
var numItemsToDelete = $scope.CompaniesList.length - index;
$scope.CompaniesList.splice(index, numItemsToDelete);
```